# WebResource.axd : The stylesheet ..../WebResource.axd was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".

Tags: asp.net

Our website is partly SSL enabled. Previously, we were getting following error in the browser when accessing SSL enabled pages:

"This page contains both secure and nonsecure items. Do you want to display the nonsecure items? "

We fixe dit by putting webresource.axd file in the secure section of web.config file. This resolved the error.

However, now the non secured pages are generating the following error:
 The stylesheet ..../WebResource.axd was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".

Do I need put check in global.asax file so that when it is non secure page then webresource.axd file should not be treated secured. How to do it? Any examples would be great.